# bash: How to store output of set of commands in 2 variables, err, combined in exact order as executed?

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, io-redirection

What we have is a set of commands including script files to be executed, a command string which can be executed.
We want to execute these commands and store the stderr output to a variable (lets say "err") and combined output of stderr and stdout to another variable ("combined").

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
cmds="<cmd1>; <cmd2>; <cmd3>;"

<cmd4>;
<cmd5>;
<cmd6>;
<cmd7>;
eval $cmds;
./myscript.sh

err=<some magic>
combined=<some magic>
```

So, variable `$err` should contain all the errors and `$combined` should contain combined output of the commands in exactly that order in which the commands were executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your output and errors to separate files and at end read them and put in variable.

For collecting output use `foo >>outputs.file` and for error use `foo 2>>errors.file` so the command will be like this `foo >>outputs.file 2>>errors.file`

`foo` is your command and `>>` means append to file. if you use single `>` it will truncate the file before writing in it.

and for putting file contains in a variable use `myvar=$(cat outputs.file)`
. no space before and after equal sign

Comment: This will give the errors and successful outputs into two different variables, but what I want is errors in one variable and combined output of errors and all other outputs in another variable, and crucial requirement is the order of lines must be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
cmds="<cmd1>; <cmd2>; <cmd3>;"

$(
    exec 3>"combined.log" 2> >(tee "err.log" >&3) 1> >(tee "out.log" >&3)
    <cmd4>;
    <cmd5>;
    <cmd6>;
    <cmd7>;
    eval $cmds;
    ./myscript.sh
)

out=$(cat "out.log")
err=$(cat "err.log")
combined=$(cat "combined.log")

echo -e "OUT :: \n\n$out \n\n"
echo -e "ERR :: \n\n$err \n\n"
echo -e "COMB :: \n\n$combined \n\n"
```

The line `3>"combined.log"` set the stream 3 to a file `combined.log`.
The commands are executed in a subshell, in which we are "tee"ing stderr and stdout to separate files and finally redirecting all these outputs to fd 3.

Comment: But is there any other way we can print the output and store in variables simultaneously as well as in realtime?